# test class for future callout Json.deserialise

Tags: apex, unit-test, json

My Class

```
global class CreditActionSessionObjMgmt
{
    @future(callout=true)
    static webservice void deleteSessionRecord(String sessionRecIds)
    {
        if(sessionRecIds != null )
        {
            List<nForce__Session__c> objList = (List<nForce__Session__c>)system.JSON.deserialize(sessionRecIds,List<nForce__Session__c>.Class);

            if(objList != null && objList.size()>0)
            {
                System.debug('Delete records:'+objList);

                delete objList;    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test class i have written is

```
@istest
public class CreditActionSessionObjMgmt_test{

    static testmethod void deleteSession(){
     string str = ' { [ {"attributes" : {"type" : "nForce__Session__c","url" : "/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/nForce__Session__c/0039000001QYYa4AAH" },"Id" : "0039000001QYYa4AAH", "Name" : "Burlington Textiles Corp of America"}} ]}';
            test.starttest();
            CreditActionSessionObjMgmt.deleteSessionRecord(str);
        test.stoptest();
    }

}
```

Error Im getting

> System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of
>   List/Set Stack Trace  Class.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1
>   Class.CreditActionSessionObjMgmt.deleteSessionRecord: line 8, column 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As error says `List` starts with `[` and ends with `]`. Also I notice extra `}` inside the array. Try below in test class:

```
string str = '[{"attributes":{"type":"nForce__Session__c","url":"/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/nForce__Session__c/0039000001QYYa4AAH"},"Id":"0039000001QYYa4AAH","Name":"Burlington Textiles Corp of America"}]';
```

**NOTE:**

For understanding better, you can run below in anonymous apex and check:

```
System.debug(JSON.serialize([SELECT Id, Name FROM nForce__Session__c WHERE Id='0039000001QYYa4AAH']));
```

Comment: +1 nice answer!

Comment: Now im getting error as 'System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error'.Here nForce__Session__c object is coming from managed package

Comment: Does the test user has delete permission?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using hard coded `JSON` to feed the records to your method to test the `delete` functionality.

`Delete` method requires the `Id` of the record which needs to be deleted and in your method, you are passing that `Id` in `JSON` as the hard coded value. If that record does not exist in the database, it will give you runtime exception. Your test method won't be able to find that record because your `seeAllData` attribute is by default set to `false` unless explicitly mentioned and you have not inserted any record of type `nForce__Session__c` in your test class.

Ideally I would write a test method like below by inserting the records and then testing it by passing a JSON and verifying if those records are getting deleted or not.

```
@istest
public class CreditActionSessionObjMgmt_test{
    static testmethod void deleteSession(){
        List<nForce__Session__c> objList = new List<nForce__Session__c>();
        nForce__Session__c obj1 = new nForce__Session__c();
        obj1.Name = 'Burlington Textiles Corp of America';
        objList.add(obj1);

        nForce__Session__c obj2 = new nForce__Session__c();
        obj2.Name = 'Burlington Textiles Corp of America';
        objList.add(obj2);

        insert objList;

        string str = JSON.serialize([SELECT Id, Name FROM nForce__Session__c]);

        Test.StartTest();
            CreditActionSessionObjMgmt.deleteSessionRecord(str);
        Test.StopTest();

        system.assertEquals(0,[SELECT count() FROM nForce__Session__c])
    }
}
```

And regarding the error you are getting, as error message suggests, the `JSON` you have used in invalid i.e. if you are trying to deserialize the `JSON` to `List<nForce__Session__c>` then you will have to have the JSON in array format. The square brackets `[` `]` are used to declare JSON array.

You can read about JSON arrays at [this](https://restfulapi.net/json-array/) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) links.

Before you pass a string of `JSON`, it is always better to validate the `JSON` at any online `JSON` validator like [JSONLINT](https://jsonlint.com/).

So your `JSON` after validation should be

```
string str = '[{"attributes":{"type":"nForce__Session__c","url":"/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/nForce__Session__c/0039000001QYYa4AAH"},"Id":"0039000001QYYa4AAH","Name":"Burlington Textiles Corp of America"}]';
```

This above `JSON` would give you `List<nForce__Session__c>` with one instance of `nForce__Session__c`.

Comment: Now im getting error as 'System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error'.Here nForce__Session__c object is coming from managed package